# What is this ODE saying

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(1 + x^2)dy - dx = xdx$
It's not that I can't solve it but on it's own it makes no sense. Could you explain what it's really saying

Comment: You can rearrange it as $y'(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}$. So it's telling you what the derivative of $y$ is actually.

Comment: But does it make immediate sense on it's own without the rearrangement

Comment: @NeoPlato In my opinion it is at least bad notation and at worst non-sense

Comment: @NeoPlato If you accept that $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are symbols we can manipulate, then you can think of it as an obfuscated way to write the derivative.

Comment: @bjorn93 Ok. That's a strange way to view math but I guess it works

Comment: What is this ODE saying ? Please integrate me !!

Comment: That's a nice math joke

Comment: Thank you Neo.....

Comment: That makes me sound like the Matrix character. I like it

Comment: @NeoPlato: Once you integrate the ODE you could talk about how $y(x)$ behaves. Or you could analyze $y'(x)$. It is unclear how you want a user to answer your question. What sort of specific details are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Re-arranging we can rewrite it as $(1+x^2)dy/dx-1=x$ or $dy/dx=(x+1)/(1+x^2)$ and solving gives $y(x)=c_1+log(x^2+1)/2+arctan(x)$. Logarithmic functions can be used to model exponential growth like radioactivity or bacterial growth, etc..
Various differentials, derivatives, and functions become related via equations, such that a differential equation is a result that describes dynamically changing phenomena, evolution, and variation. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)

sketch: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/isw5isxmtd

Comment: Nice. I actually picked it from a picture on a site